# Custom style to jQuery UI dialogs

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am trying to change jQuery UI dialog's default styles to something similar to this -

[image]

I got it to close changing some CSS in jQuery UI.

```
.ui-widget {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    background: #F9F9F9;
    border: 1px solid #90d93f;
    color: #222222;
}

.ui-dialog {
    left: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

#success {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui-widget-header {
    background: #b0de78;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    padding: 0.1em .5em;
    position: relative;
        font-size: 1em;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="popup-msg">
    <div id="loading">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
        <h3>Please wait a few seconds.</h3>
    </div>  
    
    <div id="success" title="Hurray,">
        <p>User table is updated.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[THIS IS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/23/)

But when I add this style its apply to all my dialogs. Can anybody tell me how can I avoid from this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that is not a strange behavior! Otherwise, you have to define other class names to the dialogues that you want it to be different!

Comment: Can you tell me which element do I need to add a class? I tried adding a class to this `<div id="success" title="Hurray,">` but its now working

Answer (score 68, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/qP8DY/24/

You can add a class (such as "success-dialog" in my example) to div#success, either directly in your HTML, or in your JavaScript by adding to the dialogClass option, as I've done.

```
$('#success').dialog({
    height: 50,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: true,
    dialogClass: 'no-close success-dialog'
});
```

Then just add the success-dialog class to your CSS rules as appropriate.  To indicate an element with two (or more) classes applied to it, just write them all together, with no spaces in between.  For example:

```
.ui-dialog.success-dialog {
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: .8em;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can specify a custom class to the top element of the dialog via the option `dialogClass`

```
$("#success").dialog({
    ...
    dialogClass:"myClass",
    ...
});
```

Then you can target this class in CSS via `.myClass.ui-dialog`.

Answer (score 5):

The solution only solves part of the problem, it may let you style the container and contents but doesn't let you change the titlebar. I developed a workaround of sorts but adding an id to the dialog div, then using jQuery .prev to change the style of the div which is the previous sibling of the dialog's div. This works because when jQueryUI creates the dialog, your original div becomes a sibling of the new container, but the title div is a the immediately previous sibling to your original div but neither the container not the title div has an id to simplify selecting the div.

HTML

```
<button id="dialog1" class="btn btn-danger">Warning</button>
<div title="Nothing here, really" id="nonmodal1">
  Nothing here
</div>
```

You can use CSS to style the main section of the dialog but not the title

```
.custom-ui-widget-header-warning {
  background: #EBCCCC;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

You need some JS to style the title

```
$(function() {
                   $("#nonmodal1").dialog({
                     minWidth: 400,
                     minHeight: 'auto',
                     autoOpen: false,
                     dialogClass: 'custom-ui-widget-header-warning',
                     position: {
                       my: 'center',
                       at: 'left'
                     }
                   });
        
                   $("#dialog1").click(function() {
                     if ($("#nonmodal1").dialog("isOpen") === true) {
                       $("#nonmodal1").dialog("close");
                     } else {
                       $("#nonmodal1").dialog("open").prev().css('background','#D9534F');
                     
                     }
                   });
    });
```

The example only shows simple styling (background) but you can make it as complex as you wish.

You can see it in action here:

https://codepen.io/chris-hore/pen/OVMPay